# JsonIgnore & XmlElement annotations conflict

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, jackson

I've faced issue to combine JAXB and Jackson annotation together:

```
public class Document {

    String someField;

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "someWrapper")
    @XmlElement(name = "someElement")   
    List<String> someCollection;
}
```

I need to be able to marshall and unmarshall field 'someCollection' to xml, but to have the opportunity to serialize 'Document' object to json without such field.

But this field appears in final json string

Answer (score 0):

So, if I've understood right - Jackson sees both JsSON and XML annotations. So I can not force to serialize something and do not serialize in the same moment.

It is not possible, I think